# Error informing a Timestamp field which comes from a file .parquet

Tags: scala

I'm trying to inform a Timestamp field with the date when I get it, I compile the code but it shows me a  Nullpointer.

public class SkeletonTransform implements Transform {

```
@Override
public Map<String, Dataset<Row>> transform(Map<String, Dataset<Row>> map) {
    Dataset<Row>dataset = map.get("TINCLDBC");
    SparkSession s= dataset.sparkSession();

    Date nowDate = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());

    dataset.withColumn("GF_AUDIT_DATE",
            when(col("GF_AUDIT_DATE").isNull(), nowDate)
            .otherwise(col("GF_AUDIT_DATE")));

    if(!"true".equalsIgnoreCase(InputParams.get("COMPLETE")) && map.get("CONTROL_DATE") != null){
        Dataset<Date> ds_fec =map.get("CONTROL_DATE").as(Encoders.DATE());
        if (ds_fec !=null && !ds_fec.isEmpty()){
            Date date = ds_fec.collectAsList().get(0);
            dataset = dataset.filter(dataset.col("GF_AUDIT_DATE").geq(date));

        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

}

Comment: Which line of code throws a NPE? in your second line you have unsafe getting key "TINCLDBC" from map:
`Dataset<Row>dataset = map.get("TINCLDBC")`
and after use `dataset.sparkSession()` but if `dataset` is `null` it may be cause of NPE.

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for your help, I  finally found the problem, when I was doing the dataset.withColumn, I had to assing it to another dataset and then set it.